# QByteArray data format explanation

Tags: c++, c, char, ascii, qbytearray

I am confused about QByteArray data. Can someone please explain the below scenario for me. 
[image]

Here data type for each array index is char. I understand some of those values. Like `74 'J'` 
I understand the first one is ASCII and second one is the corresponding character. But what is the meaning of `-1 '\\377'`

Also what does the below gui means??  I sent the QByteArray of above to a function which takes the QByteArray as `unsigned char* source`. The below gui is showing the value of that `source`.
[image]

The main confusing part is the first line's value `0x87089e8 "\377\330\377\340"`

Comment: It would help if you told us what you stored in it.

Comment: This data holds a network request reply which contains a jpeg image. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`char` in C/C++ is a *signed* 1-byte integer. This GUI is simply expressing that value as a signed decimal number, and the equivalent [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) character.

You're asking about the byte value -1, which can be interpretted in the following ways:

```
Binary     11111111
Octal      0377
Hex        0xFF
Decimal    -1    (Signed)
           255   (Unsigned)

ASCII      \377
           \xFF
```

Note that there isn't a standard printable ASCII character for 255, which is why they show it like they do.

Another Example:

```
Binary     01001010
Octal      0112
Hex        0x4A
Decimal    74    (Signed)
           74   (Unsigned)
ASCII      'J'
```

Comment: Hi I understand the part you explained very well. Thanks. I added another part in this question. Can you please answer that too? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm answering about the meaning of `0x87089e8 "\377\330\377\340"`.

`0x87089e8` is the value of the `source` pointer, i.e. it's an address
in memory. `"\377\330\377\340"` is the character string stored at that
address, written as octal escape sequences. It's written this way
because none of these characters is ASCII (ASCII goes only from 0 to
127). In hex, the string of bytes is `ff d8 ff e0 00`. The `00` at the end
is interpreted as and end-of-string mark (ASCII NULL).